# Typo on proof of Riemann Lebesgue proofwiki(?)

Tags: integration, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, proof-explanation

I was wondering if there is a typo for the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_Lemma).

Should it not be written as:

> ...
>   Now let $\displaystyle g_N = \sum_1^N c_n \chi_{\left({a_i, b_i}\right)} $, a simple function.
>
> Then the same argument shows that the theorem holds for all such simple functions which are dense in $L^1$ ... Call it $g_N \left({x}\right)$, such that $\displaystyle \int \left|{f - g_N}\right| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Yes, it would seem so. $f\in L^1$ is already established. Not sure if a typo, exactly. Perhaps, a peculiar style to store information under a variable that's already in use.

Comment: Perhaps consider asking this again at the corresponding talk page at ProofWiki.